# Adding Additional Signatures

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I created a simple web form that a user will make some choices on and then when they submit that form will redirect them to Docusign to have them sign the actual form with the information they had entered burned into the form.

My question is the form could require additional signatures but that will depend on when the user is actually filling out the form.  So my question is there a way with the API to add additional signatures.  I also won't know the names of those potential extra signers until the user submits the form.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You create the envelope dynamically only after the user submit the form. At that point you know how many signers and all the information you need I assume. So you create the envelope with that in mind.
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-in-app-embedded should help.
Simple C# code (add singer2 etc. for your use case):

```
Signer signer1 = new Signer {
        Email = signerEmail,
        Name = signerName,
        ClientUserId = signerClientId,
        RecipientId = "1"
    };
   
    // Create signHere fields (also known as tabs) on the documents,
    // We're using anchor (autoPlace) positioning
    //
    // The DocuSign platform seaches throughout your envelope's
    // documents for matching anchor strings.
    SignHere signHere1 = new SignHere
    {
        AnchorString = "/sn1/",
        AnchorUnits = "pixels",
        AnchorXOffset = "10",
        AnchorYOffset = "20"
    };
```

Comment: So just to confirm what you are saying:  When I create the template I can only have one signature/role.  Then through the api I can create however many signatures I need to complete the document without needing to specify it in the UI prior to?  Also with regards to the way of adding signature blocks can I also do the same for date signed?

Comment: no, that's not what I'm saying. I didn't know you're using a template. You can have as many roles/recipients in a template as you want.

Comment: the tabs/blocks as you call them, are associated with a specific role/recipient.

Comment: Date Signed is auto-filled by the system when that particular recipient associated with that tag signed.

Comment: But with the templates how do you make signatures optional?  I know there are different options but I would need to make different signatures for the roles required depending on logic on my end.

Comment: you can make any tab optional with or without template, how are you creating them? via API or via UI?

Comment: Well I create the template through the UI, however I was giving Names & email addresses through the api.  I'm not sure if I should add all possible Signatures/Roles through the UI or add them through the api.